# Homomorphism from $Q_8$ to cyclic group of order $2$

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

I am trying to find a surjective homomorphism from the quaternion group $Q_8 = \{\pm 1, \pm i, \pm j, \pm k\}$ to the cyclic group of order $2$, $H = \{e,x\}$.

I am not sure where to get started on this. I certainly need to map $1$ to $e$ since a homomorphism preserves the identity, and I know that I need to map inverses to inverses. As $H$ only has two elements, almost any map I write down that doesn't send every element of $Q_8$ to the identity is surjective as a map of sets, but that doesn't guarantee that the map respects the group operation. If the groups had the same size, I could write down the multiplication tables, expecting the groups to be "the same but for labels" (as in the case of an isomorphism) and that would inform the map, but since the groups are surely not isomorphic, I don't know a way to derive any insight from the multiplication table.

I would greatly appreciate some hints and some help on how to get started.

Comment: 1) How many elements do you need to map to the identity? 2) What can you say about the kernel of a homomorphism?

Comment: Hint: pick some element besides $1$ to send to $x$, then see what implications that has for other elements of $Q_8$. If you run out of implications, pick some other element and somewhere to send it, then continue.

Comment: Note: the [tag:proof-explanation] tag is for when you already have a proof, for which you request an explanation.

Comment: @Shaun Sorry about that, and thank you for fixing it.

Comment: @GregMartin So I tried to define $\phi(i) = x$. As $ij = k$, I need $\phi(k) = x \phi(j)$. If $\phi(k) = e$, then $\phi(j) = x$. If $\phi(j) = e$, then $\phi(k) = x$, so $\phi(j) \neq \phi(k)$. I think I can choose arbitrarily where to send $j$, for instance, and then choose the opposite for $k$. I don't see an implication for negatives, so I can probably proceed in the same way and deduce $\phi(-j) \neq \phi(-k)$ and so forth. Is this on the right track?

Comment: The right track indeed! Does $i^2=-1$ provide any information? Though also think about Cem's comment, which can lead to a quicker solution.

Answer (score 1):

$Q_8$ has a subgroup of order four, $\langle i\rangle $.  (Actually it has three. )  It's  also normal,  because of index $2$.

Thus you can simply take the canonical projection: $$\pi:Q_8\to Q_8/\langle i\rangle\cong\Bbb Z_2 $$.